# Scroll to element that is not on screen and has shared object ID but with unique user determined text (Android / Java)

Tags: java, android, scroll, navigation

I'm trying to navigate to an element (and click on) that share the same ID as other object but has different text on it. Some of these elements, depending on other variables, might or might not be present on screen. On my device, scrolling works but on some devices or on emulator it doesn't always work. Please suggest an alternative to my temporary scrolling as I'm kind of at a loss of options on what to do.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.1
Build #IC-181.5540.7 built on July 11, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64

JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

```
public static void environment(AndroidDriver driver, String environmentName, String configStatus, String deviceType, String configName) {
    List elementsFilterPage = driver.findElements(By.id("com.digiflare.videa:id/filter_item_text"));
    System.out.println("There is this much Environment config file elements = " + elementsFilterPage.size()); // THIS IS TO SELECT THE ENVIRONMENT OF THE CONFIG FILE. MAKE SURE TO CHANGE THE "Staging" TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsFilterPage.size(); i++) {
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) elementsFilterPage.get(i);
        if (element.getText().equals(environmentName)) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
        TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);   // ONLY NEEDED TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS THE OTHER ELEMENTS FILTER PAGE. MIGHT NEED TO EDIT IF YOU HAVE LOTS OF ELEMENTS ON PAGE TO ACCESS BRANDS, STATUS, ETC
        ta.press(point(962, 1329))
                .moveTo(point(962, 345))
                .waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(3000)))
                .release()
                .perform();
    }

    System.out.println("There is this much Status config file elements = " + elementsFilterPage.size());  // THIS IS TO SELECT THE STATUS OF THE CONFIG FILE MAKE SURE TO CHANGE THE "Published" TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsFilterPage.size(); i++) {
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) elementsFilterPage.get(i);
        if (element.getText().equals(configStatus))    {
            element.click();
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("There is this much Phone config file elements = " + elementsFilterPage.size());  // THIS IS TO SELECT THE DEVICE TYPE OF THE CONFIG FILE EDIT VARIABLE TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsFilterPage.size(); i++) {
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) elementsFilterPage.get(i);
        if (element.getText().equals(deviceType)) {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    WebElement doneButton = driver.findElementById("com.digiflare.videa:id/edition_done_menu_item");
    doneButton.click();

    Utils.waitForPresence(driver, 6, "com.digiflare.videa:id/edition_name");
    List elementsConfigFilesPage = driver.findElements(By.id("com.digiflare.videa:id/edition_name"));
    System.out.println("There is this much Config Files elements = " + elementsConfigFilesPage.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsConfigFilesPage.size(); i++) {
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) elementsConfigFilesPage.get(i);

        if (element.getText().equals(configName))  { // THIS IS WHERE YOU'LL BE ABLE TO ENTER THE LATEST PUBLISHED / TO BE TESTED CONFIG FILE. EDIT VARIABLE TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some searching on my own, I found the following solution. I created a method which would scroll the screen until it found the specified text and click on it. Here it is for those who would perhaps have the same issues as I had :

public static void scrollclickText (AndroidDriver driver, String visibleText){

```
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+visibleText+"\").instance(0))").click();
```